# Add User Name to File Path

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am attempting to add a username to file path so I can create a directory that contains their username.

This is how I want my User Folder to Look:

`D:\Test Space\ArtP$`

When I do this in a Shell:

```
PS > $samAccountName = "ArtP"
PS > $user_folder = "D:\Test Space\$samAccountName$"
PS > $user_folder
D:\Test Space\ArtP$
```

It works as expected. I then try this in a script that is supposed to do this on a remote server:

```
 $samAccountName = "ArtP"
 $user_folder = "D:\Test Space\$samAccountName$"
 invoke-command -computername remote_server -scriptblock {
     new-item -path $user_folder -type directory -Force
 }
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemComm
   and
```

It is saying my path is null and I believe there is some discrepancy about how the shell interprets quotes and how the script is. How do I get my user name in the file path above properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the section about Passing Local Values in [How to pass arguments for remote commands](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/12/29/arguments-for-remote-commands.aspx)

```
$samAccountName = "ArtP"
$user_folderLocalValue = "D:\Test Space\$samAccountName"
```

With Param:

```
invoke-command -computername remote_server -scriptblock {
param($user_folder)
new-item -path $user_folder -type directory -Force
} -Args $user_folderLocalValue
```

or with $args

```
invoke-command -computername remote_server -scriptblock {
new-item -path $args[0] -type directory -Force
} -Args $user_folderLocalValue
```

Comment: Excellent. I did not realize that you had to treat local vars in such a manner for remote execution.